# How to get a specif node of an xml using child node name in LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've an XML document like given below

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C name="C1" >value1</C>
    <C name="C2">value2</C>
    <C name="C3">value3</C>
    <C name="C4">value4</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

I want to get a specific node using the node name . How can I achieve that using LINQ. I'm not so good with LINQ

Comment: please post what you have actually tried. we might fix the problem you are facing. Thx

Comment: What kind of node? Based on what: the name, the attribute, the value? Please be specific.

Comment: @AndreiV based on the attribute name  I want to get its value

Comment: @Optimus please, next time provide code which you have tried. Otherwise it looks like you haven't tried anything

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy string value = (string)doc.Root.Element("A").Elements("B").FirstOrDefault ... this is what I tried before and I'm  stuck with my code when I reach FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var value = (string)doc.Root.Element("B").Elements("C")
                       .FirstOrDefault(c => (string)c.Attribute("name") == "C3");
```

Or with XPath

```
var value = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement("A/B/C[@name='C3']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergey's answer is more accurate and readable. However, **if** you don't care about the other nodes **and if** you just want something quick based **only** on nodes that have a particular attribute, you can also use this:

```
string value = "";
value = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("name").Value == "C2").FirstOrDefault() != null ?
        xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("name").Value == "C2").FirstOrDefault().Value : "";
```